# Excal-VBA: Convert a string of number numbers to rows and add recurrent name after

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an issue which I use a lot of manual time on currently.

I have following simple data:

[image]

And I wish to convert all the accounts downwards with the name next to the accounts in another column. Currently I do this by using the 'text to columns' function and then manually copy the names down.. HARD work.. :)

This is an example of my wish scenario..

[image]

Hope you are able to help..

Thanks a lot
Kristoffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following short macro will take data from *Sheet1* and output records in *Sheet2*:

```
Sub DataReorganizer()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, N As Long
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    j = 1

    For i = 2 To N
        v1 = s1.Cells(i, 1)
        ary = Split(s1.Cells(i, 2), ";")
        For Each a In ary
            s2.Cells(j, 1).Value = v1
            s2.Cells(j, 2).Value = a
            j = j + 1
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

Input:

[image]

and output:

[image]

Comment: This is genuis! thanks a million.. works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(1).Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1)
    Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1)


    Dim vPaste



    Dim lTotalRows As Long

    Dim lPass As Long
    For lPass = 0 To 1

        Dim rowLoop As Excel.Range
        For Each rowLoop In rng.Rows

            Dim sName As String
            sName = rowLoop.Cells(1, 1)

            Dim sAccounts As String
            sAccounts = rowLoop.Cells(1, 2)

            Dim vSplitAccounts As Variant
            vSplitAccounts = VBA.Split(sAccounts, ";")

            If lPass = 0 Then
                lTotalRows = lTotalRows + UBound(vSplitAccounts) + 1
            Else

                Dim vLoop As Variant
                For Each vLoop In vSplitAccounts
                    lTotalRows = lTotalRows + 1
                    vPaste(lTotalRows, 1) = sName
                    vPaste(lTotalRows, 2) = vLoop


                Next vLoop
            End If

        Next
        If lPass = 0 Then
            ReDim vPaste(1 To lTotalRows, 1 To 2)
            lTotalRows = 0

        End If

    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = "Name"
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = "Account"

    Dim rngPaste As Excel.Range
    Set rngPaste = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(2).Cells(2, 1).Resize(lTotalRows, 2)

    rngPaste.Value2 = vPaste

End Sub
```